# Basic CSS (Positioning vs Float) what I can't figure out

Tags: css, positioning, css-float, css-position

I'm looking for a solution. I have a CSS styled page. The page is generated with Rails. The layout contains a `div id="wrapper` for the fix site width and the `margin: 0 auto` thing.

**Details of my problem:**

---

There is a header section, a navigation section and the container (and oc. the footer). The container have two columns. The content and the rightSideBar.

Ok, I start to generate the dynamic thing in the content area. This page is about predictions. I have tarot cards in a spread then every card is cycled threw again to have the explanations of the meaning of the cards.

The spread box at the top of the content area:

```
div#spread_box {
 width:620px; 
 background-color:#392b3f; 
 margin: 15px 15px 10px 10px; 
 display:block; 
 overflow:auto;  
 position:relative; 
 clear:both;}
```

I have images in it what I want to be positioned perfectly one place, so I use absolute positioning.

```
div#spread_box img  {border: 1px solid #000000; display: block; height: 120px; position: absolute; width: 71px;}

div#spread_box #kelta1  {left: 115px; top:168px;-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3); z-index: 500;}
div#spread_box #kelta2  {left: 115px; top:168px;}
div#spread_box #kelta3  {left: 115px; top:45px;}
div#spread_box #kelta4  {left: 115px; top:291px;}
div#spread_box #kelta5  {left: 20px; top:168px;}
div#spread_box #kelta6  {left: 210px; top:168px;}
div#spread_box #kelta7  {left: 310px; top:395px;}
div#spread_box #kelta8  {left: 310px; top:270px;}
div#spread_box #kelta9  {left: 310px; top:145px;}
div#spread_box #kelta10 {left: 310px; top:20px;}
```

This is the spread box. *As you can see, I used the positioning technique to have this at the right place.* Than comes the Rails generated content data. Each block have a `class="card_detail"`. In this there are 3 things: A short text in a `<p>` that details the position. Under that in two columns the picture of the card and the explanation of it.

*Because this is database generated content, I used the float technique.*

```
div.explanation_box     { width:600px; background-color:#392b3f; border: 1px solid #000; margin: 15px 15px 10px 10px; text-align:justify; padding: 10px; overflow:auto;}
div.explanation_box p   { width:475px; }
div.explanation_pos     { margin:5px; display:block;}
div.explanation_pos p   { width:575px; }
div.explanation_card    { width:100px; float:left;}
div.explanation_img     { margin:5px; width:100px; float:left;}
div.explanation_pos img { width:100px; }
```

There is a container box called explanation_box with a fixed `width` and an `overflow:auto` property. The explanation_box is in the normal workflow including float positioned elements.

**Sympthoms of my problem**

---

1. If I give an exact `height:600px;` to the spread_box (the container element) than everything is fine. However if I display one and only one card, than there will be a huge unused area. [image]
2. If I take away the height parameter of the spread box than the whole thing is gone! [image]
3. And If the `overflow:auto` selector is removed, than the floating elements are going up, under the absolute positioned elements.

   [image]
4. If I use overflow auto and the fix height with smaller px size than the appearing content, than there will be the slider on the right side and the content will be cropped.

**The Question at last**

---

*So, how can I make the spread_box have a dynamic height included a fixed positioned spread?*

The content of the spread_box depends on the FORM that sends the data. So there can be everything from a single card to a really complex spread. This is why I need this!

Comment: Why you take away the height parameter of the spread box? You cannot do another Box? Can you post your project/code somewhere?

Comment: @Kael: No freehand cricles -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, change `overflow: auto` to `overflow: hidden` to remove any chance of scrollbars.

Due to the fact that your cards are *absolutely positioned,* and the height of all the cards together is *variable*, you **need** to work out the combined height of the cards. Then, you need to set this calculated height on `#spread_box`.

You can calculate the height in either of two places:

- In your Ruby code. You know which cards you're outputting, and the height of each card and the `top` values are known to you. This might be difficult to get right, but has the advantage that it will work if JavaScript is disabled, which brings me to the next option..
- Using JavaScript. This is the cleanest way to resolve your problem. Some JavaScript, or even just a few lines of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) can calculate the height of the cards.

Comment: If you'd like to take the JavaScript option (preferably also with jQuery), let me know and I'll help. Also: which browsers/versions do you need to support?

Comment: I accepted your idea, but this isn't the exact answer for my problem I think. Every spread I use includes a uniq css. So I can set the size here. BUT! Is there other solution? A pure CSS one? What do you think?

Comment: If you're absolutely positioning the cards, there is *no other solution*, sorry. I don't know enough about how the cards are laid out to suggest a solution that doesn't involve absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind upon viewing the last image is that it looks like you don't have a "clearfix", in other words the following element after all your floaters (preferably at the end of each *large wrapping containers*:

```
<div style="clear: both; height: 1px;"></div>
```

This would act as a large wall that keeps all the floaters inside their given element. Let me know if you're already using it, or if it works/doesn't work for you!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The floats work perfectly. This isn't a clear problem. Anyway I tried your solution and nothing happens, as I thought.